# exporting contacts of outlook into excel/sharepoint using outlook add in

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, export-to-excel, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi

I am working in a project where i have to access outlook contacts and have to give specific domain-name and export into sharepoint list or excel sheet .
i wonder if outlook REST api be usefull to access contacts and if accessible will i be able to compare the inputted domain name with other contacts in outlook and export through a click in excel .
is there any other way i can do this project using "add in" only
please note:-(yes there are many ways we can export the excel sheet and all but i want to automate this thing using an "add in")

Comment: Hi, you can access contacts through Microsoft Graph API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview and to be more precise, kindly have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-contacts-concept-overview .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook web add-ins work under the context of currently selected item in Outlook only. To access other item you may consider using [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api) which is a RESTful web API that enables you to access Microsoft Cloud service resources.

See [Outlook personal contacts API overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-contacts-concept-overview) for more information about contacts API.